# Index was outside the bounds of the array in @Scripts.Render

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-optimization

For each controller have a folder (with the same name controler), and for each action a script file.

[image: Folder structure]

For each file is creating a bundle following the pattern: *"~/Scripts/Controllers/{controller-name}/{filename-without-extension}"*

```
bundles.IncludePerFile(new DirectoryInfo(server.MapPath("~/Scripts/Controllers")), "~/Scripts/Controllers/{0}/{1}", 
    (dir,file) => string.Format("~/Scripts/Controllers/{0}/{1}", dir, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file)), "*.js");
```

*`IncludePerFile` is an extension method I created to perform this task*

Then one bundle for: `~/Scripts/Controllers/processos/pasta` should exist!
**And to confirm this:**

[image: Bundle exist]

**So far so correct! The bundle exists!**

### Running app

When I run the application, the following error occurs:

[image: Bundle error]

> [Full image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEbJg.jpg)

#### Wrongly and inefficient to repair the error:

If I change this:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/Controllers/processos/pasta")
```

to this:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/Controllers/processos/pasta.js")
```

No error is generated. But the file is not minified since there is effectively a bundle. (I have already put in release mode and published application!)

### Full error

```
Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Source Error: 


Line 3:  @section js {
Line 4:     @*@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/Controllers/processos/Pasta.js", "~/Scripts/Controllers/processos/display.js")*@
Line 5:     @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/Controllers/processos/pasta")
Line 6:     @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/Controllers/processos/display.js")
Line 7:  

Source File: w:\Clients\creditoimobiliariobb\sistema\src\CreditoImobiliarioBB\CreditoImobiliarioBB.Web\Views\processos\display.cshtml    Line: 5 

Stack Trace: 


[IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.]
   System.String.get_Chars(Int32 index) +0
   Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.CssParser.Append(Object obj, TokenType tokenType) +402
   Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.CssParser.AppendCurrent() +74
   Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.CssParser.SkipToClose() +744
   Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.CssParser.SkipToEndOfStatement() +232
   Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.CssParser.ParseRule() +574
   Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.CssParser.ParseStylesheet() +1235
   Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.CssParser.Parse(String source) +897
   Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.Minifier.MinifyStyleSheet(String source, CssSettings settings) +419
   System.Web.Optimization.CssMinify.Process(BundleContext context, BundleResponse response) +302
   System.Web.Optimization.Bundle.ApplyTransforms(BundleContext context, String bundleContent, IEnumerable`1 bundleFiles) +207
   System.Web.Optimization.Bundle.GenerateBundleResponse(BundleContext context) +355
   System.Web.Optimization.Bundle.GetBundleResponse(BundleContext context) +104
   System.Web.Optimization.BundleResolver.GetBundleContents(String virtualPath) +254
   System.Web.Optimization.AssetManager.EliminateDuplicatesAndResolveUrls(IEnumerable`1 refs) +435
   System.Web.Optimization.AssetManager.DeterminePathsToRender(IEnumerable`1 assets) +1029
   System.Web.Optimization.AssetManager.RenderExplicit(String tagFormat, String[] paths) +75
   System.Web.Optimization.Scripts.RenderFormat(String tagFormat, String[] paths) +292
   System.Web.Optimization.Scripts.Render(String[] paths) +51
```

Comment: Did you find the answer to this?

Comment: I`m getting this error. The malicious bundle includes standard MVC5 Bootstrap js assets.

Comment: Answer is too simple :) You have to update your packages (Microsoft Web Optimization & WebGrease) http://fsou1.com/styles-render-index-was-outside-the-bounds-of-the-array/

Answer (score 33):

I've had the same error in this question: [StyleBundle Index was outside the bounds of the array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21809904/stylebundle-index-was-outside-the-bounds-of-the-array)

And answer is pretty simple: you have to update your `Microsoft Web Optimization` & `WebGrease` packages (at this time 1.1.2 & 1.6.0 versions)

Answer (score 5):

I would verify that all the elements of your

```
IncludePerFile(new DirectoryInfo(server.MapPath("~/Scripts/Controllers")), "~/Scripts/Controllers/{0}/{1}", 
(dir,file) => string.Format("~/Scripts/Controllers/{0}/{1}", dir, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file)), "*.js")
```

are putting in the created bundles exactly what you think they're putting in.

I got this error at run time when the wrong type of file is included within a bundle.  i.e.

```
@Styles.Render("~/bundles/myStyleBundle");
```

actually contains a JavaScript file.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and when I tried different checking I found out that there is a selector in my css file like this that cause the problem:

**.glyphicons-icon _:-o-prefocus**,
    .glyphicons-icon {
        background-image: url(../images/glyphicons.png);
    }

it seems that Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.CssParser has a problem with **_:** css selector. I removed the line and it's working.

Comment: Thanks so much, I was using a custom bootstrap downloaded from their website and it had this selector. It seems weird that a css selector should cause the yellow screen of death but I guess it's the parsing of the css.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into a similar problem. I am using VS 2013 and MVC 5 and was updating to Bootstrap v3.0.1 in order to use a theme from Bootswatch. I updated everything using the latest Bootstrap download and the site seemed to work fine. I then grabbed the CSS for Slate from the Bootswatch site and used it in the new stylesheet, changed it in the StyleBundle and built solution. When I ran it, I got the "Index was outside the bounds of the array" error. Switch back to bootstrap.css and it worked fine.

I then used NuGet Package Manager to update all my packages... I had just installed VS 2013 and not yet updated everything. Rebuilt the solution and wallah, it works great. So I would up vote the updating your packages answser.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to update some of your nuget libraries. Try updating WebGrease

Answer (score 0):

I'm using

```
@Scripts.Render()
```

For me it was an issue with the backtik in JS file.

Sample 1

```
    let something = `some text
bla bla
`;
```

Above code thrown this exception

```
 Index and length must refer to a location within the string.
```

Sample 2

```
let something = `some text
bla bla`;
```

Now it works well, so do not keep the closing backtik at the beginning new line ...

So to find this cases in your js files do the following:

1- Press ctrl+shift+f

2- search for `\r\n``

3- enable regex
4- search in js files only