# StyleBundle Index was outside the bounds of the array

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to include all files in directory like this:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/simpliq_css").Include(
    "~/Content/simpliq/*.css"
));
```

But i got this error `Index was outside the bounds of the array`

and red line is:

`@Styles.Render("~/Content/simpliq_css")`

```
[IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.]
   System.String.get_Chars(Int32 index) +0
   Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.CssParser.Append(Object obj, TokenType tokenType) +402
   Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.CssParser.AppendCurrent() +74
   Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.CssParser.ParseElementName() +321
   Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.CssParser.ParseSimpleSelector() +54
   Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.CssParser.ParseSelector() +555
   Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.CssParser.ParseRule() +165
   Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.CssParser.ParseStylesheet() +186
   Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.CssParser.Parse(String source) +946
   Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.Minifier.MinifyStyleSheet(String source, CssSettings settings, CodeSettings scriptSettings) +439
   Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.Minifier.MinifyStyleSheet(String source, CssSettings settings) +73
   System.Web.Optimization.CssMinify.Process(BundleContext context, BundleResponse response) +302
   System.Web.Optimization.Bundle.ApplyTransforms(BundleContext context, String bundleContent, IEnumerable`1 bundleFiles) +207
   System.Web.Optimization.Bundle.GenerateBundleResponse(BundleContext context) +355
   System.Web.Optimization.Bundle.GetBundleResponse(BundleContext context) +104
   System.Web.Optimization.BundleResolver.GetBundleContents(String virtualPath) +254
   System.Web.Optimization.AssetManager.EliminateDuplicatesAndResolveUrls(IEnumerable`1 refs) +435
   System.Web.Optimization.AssetManager.DeterminePathsToRender(IEnumerable`1 assets) +1030
   System.Web.Optimization.AssetManager.RenderExplicit(String tagFormat, String[] paths) +75
   System.Web.Optimization.Styles.RenderFormat(String tagFormat, String[] paths) +293
   System.Web.Optimization.Styles.Render(String[] paths) +51
   ASP._Page_Areas_Admin_Views_Shared__Layout_cshtml.Execute() in f:\MyProjects\Fables\Fables\Fables.Web\Areas\Admin\Views\Shared\_Layout.cshtml:8
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +271
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +120
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +145
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer) +41
   System.Web.WebPages.<>c__DisplayClass7.<RenderPageCore>b__6(TextWriter writer) +335
   System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult.WriteTo(TextWriter writer) +42
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageExecutingBase.WriteTo(TextWriter writer, HelperResult content) +45
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.Write(HelperResult result) +53
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.RenderSurrounding(String partialViewName, Action`1 body) +178
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.PopContext() +347
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +154
   System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance) +695
   System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) +382
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +431
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +116
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +529
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +106
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass28.<BeginInvokeAction>b__19() +321
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1e.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1b(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +185
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +133
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +56
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +34
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +70
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +139
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +44
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +62
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +139
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__4(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +70
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +139
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +38
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9514928
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

Comment: Please post the full stack-trace of the exception!

Comment: Try changing the bundle name to different than directory like ~/bundles/css.

Comment: @FSou1 I doubt it'd make a difference, but does the same thing happen if you use `bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/simpliq_css").IncludeDirectory("~/Content/simpliq/", "*.css", false));`

Comment: Yeah, that's still the same result and i already found an answer :)

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Problem was in version of next packages:

[image]

You have to update it and problem will be solved.

Comment: For me it was just enough to update webgrease.
I didn't need to update Web Optimization Framework (my version: 1.1.3).

Comment: You could alos update it with `Install-Package WebGrease` in your Package Manager (`Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Console`)

Comment: Or to update packages from the package manager console just use : Update-Package WebGrease -ProjectName YourWebProject

Comment: unable to find package WebGrease

Comment: @Vasil Valchev, check out your current version of WebGrease & ASP.NET Web Optimization. If your version is higher , try to downgrade it (update of Microsoft ASP.NET Web Optimization Framework to version 1.1.2 and WebGrease to 1.6.0 solved my problem!).

Comment: Pretty crumby that a brand new VS 2015 solution from the MVC template is broken right out of the gate.

Comment: Installing and Upgrading WebGrease from Nuget in visual studio solved the problem for me

Answer (score 14):

I had the same problem and when I tried different checking I found out that there is a selector in my css file like this that cause the problem:

**.glyphicons-icon _:-o-prefocus**, .glyphicons-icon { background-image: url(../images/glyphicons.png); }

it seems that Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.CssParser has a problem with **_:** css selector. I removed the line and it's working.

Answer (score 14):

The same error can appear when one try to add javascript files to a StyleBundle.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error. My ASP.NET Web Optimization Framework was updated, but Bootstrap was at version 3.3.0. I updated Bootstrap to 3.3.5 and the error is gone.

Answer (score 2):

In my case it was just an extra apostrophe "`" in one of js files. ASP.NET seems to be sensitive to this particular character ([Grave accent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grave_accent)). So be sure to check your code for typos.

Answer (score 1):

Note that this can be caused by invalid JavaScript.  While working on some JavaScript, I noticed that my bundles suddenly started throwing this message.  The stack trace showed that it was blowing up on "Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSScanner.ScanTemplateLiteral".  It turns out I had inadvertently added a ` (backtick) in my JavaScript. Removing it caused everything to work again. I'm running Webgrease 1.6.0 and Microsoft ASP.NET Web Optimization Framework 1.1.2.

The bundler was not affected when the CSS had a backtick in it.