# Bootstrap 3.3.0 and Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, twitter-bootstrap-3

like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26696078/2401823) I tried to update "Microsoft ASP.NET Web Optimization Framework" but It doesn't solve my problem: I get a index out of range in

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
```

for *bootstrap.css*. If I delete the following rules:

```
_:-ms-fullscreen,
:root input[type="date"],
_:-ms-fullscreen,
:root input[type="time"],
_:-ms-fullscreen,
:root input[type="datetime-local"],
_:-ms-fullscreen,
:root input[type="month"] {
    line-height: 1.42857143;
}

    _:-ms-fullscreen.input-sm,
    :root input[type="date"].input-sm,
    _:-ms-fullscreen.input-sm,
    :root input[type="time"].input-sm,
    _:-ms-fullscreen.input-sm,
    :root input[type="datetime-local"].input-sm,
    _:-ms-fullscreen.input-sm,
    :root input[type="month"].input-sm {
        line-height: 1.5;
    }

    _:-ms-fullscreen.input-lg,
    :root input[type="date"].input-lg,
    _:-ms-fullscreen.input-lg,
    :root input[type="time"].input-lg,
    _:-ms-fullscreen.input-lg,
    :root input[type="datetime-local"].input-lg,
    _:-ms-fullscreen.input-lg,
    :root input[type="month"].input-lg {
        line-height: 1.33;
    }
```

it works. It's a "Microsoft ASP.NET Web Optimization Framework" bug or what?

Comment: It's sure not a Bootstrap bug. Guess it can't handle the browser hack in question: http://browserhacks.com/#hack-d19e53a0fdfba5ec0f283ae86175a3af

Answer (score 9):

You need to update to WebGrease 1.6.

Comment: This may resolve the OP's issue, but you should really explain why upgrading to WebGrease 1.6 will resolve the issue.

Comment: what would i do without SO?!

Answer (score 0):

Same issue with VS2013 and removing the code section as stated by Ymir works. I am not sure what are the issues will come up because of removing this code though. I would wait till Bootstrap fixes this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is CSS breaks !!!
Augustine Cost reported this issue on Microsoft site as well 
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1015447/css-parser-breaks-on-ie-hacks-in-bootstrap-3-3-0
But still there is no ideal resolution besides removing this section.

Answer (score 0):

Update the WebGrease to version 1.6

Comment: WebGrease is for optimizing CSS and JS scripts. CSS 3.3.0 should need WebGrease 1.6 to operate