# MVC5 not generating Model from Database after NuGet update

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, nuget, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore

I am creating an MVC 5 Web Application with Visual Basic using **Database First** Approach. Recently I updated **ALL** NuGet packages and after that I'm unable to create Models from the Database.

As shown below, I can not select **Tables** and other DB objects from Database to include in my Model.

[image]

When I click finish, it generates an **empty model** as shown below:

[image]

One more weird thing I noticed is: As shown in [this tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/database-first-development/setting-up-database), it should show me a checkbox that says, *Enable Extended Transact-SQL verification for common objects*, but when I open the properties of my project, it doesn't show me this checkbox.

[image]

Now, my questions are:

- If as I doubt, a NuGet package update has created this problem; which
  package is it?
- Is it possible to uninstall updates of NuGet packages
  (as we do with Windows Updates)? If yes, How?

Any help would be appreciated. Please note that,

- I've experience in Web Forms but I'm a beginner in MVC.
- This issue
  has started just after, I updated **ALL packages** when I was facing
  [this type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21809904/stylebundle-index-was-outside-the-bounds-of-the-array) of issue.
- I created 3 projects with the same approach
  before this update, and I succeeded every time generating the Models
  from Database.

Please suggest!

Answer (score 1):

Right click the .edmx file in the solution explorer and select 'open with..' Select the XML editor and open the file. Check if there are any errors in the file. Errors may show in the error list window or may show as comments in the file.