# style Bundle Index was outside the bounds of the array

Tags: asp.net-mvc

calling style bundle at layout
I updated webgrease and web.optmization

calling at Layout:-
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
Style bundle:-

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                      "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                      "~/Content/site.css",
                      "~/scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.css",
                      "~/Content/DataTables/css/dataTables.bootstrap.css",
                    "~/Content/DataTables/css/responsive.dataTables.min.css",
                       "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                        "~/Content/Site.css",
                       "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.css",
                        "~/Content/DataTables/css/dataTables.bootstrap.css",
                    "~/Content/DataTables/css/responsive.dataTables.min.css",
                         "~/Content/toastr.min.css"
                      ));
```

Solving IndexOutOfRangeException problem

Comment: Where do you see the IndexOutOfRangeException? Could you also post the stacktrace of the exception?

Comment: Did you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21809904/stylebundle-index-was-outside-the-bounds-of-the-array ?

Comment: at @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")

Comment: yes, I checked this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21809904/stylebundle-index-was-outside-the-bounds-of-the-array

Comment: Also try to check this one: http://blog.andreasgustafsson.se/javascript/styles-render-index-was-outside-the-bounds-of-the-array/. What is your bootstrap version?

Comment: I removed all css files and remained the default.I got the same result